# How to print input from user with template literals in JS? It's giving error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I'm using JS to render HTML code and would like to add user input also in that HTML for this am using template literal but its not working. It says `[object HTMLTextAreaElement]`

Am using this code.

```
<script>
function print(){
var heading = document.getElementById("heading") //I have a input tag with id heading in HTML code and type text
open = document.open("")
open.document.write(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Dummy Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <h1>${heading}</h1>
         // this line is supposed to print user input.
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
}
</script>
```

Comment: `var ? = document.getElementById("heading")`? Where's the variable you're assigning the element to?

Comment: Just added, it was in actual code but somehow I missed here.

Comment: Don't you need to print the `value` of the `heading` element?

Comment: You should be getting the value of the textarea, i.e. `var heading = document.getElementById("heading").value`

Comment: Thanks @AlonEitan and Terry I didn't used value

Comment: @oop You're welcome, you can mark Terry's answer as accepted (Or any other answer) if it helped you by clicking on the green `✓` next to the answer

Comment: @AlonEitan Just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `[object HTMLTextAreaElement]` that is printed on the page tells you exactly what the problem is: is that you are attempting to inject a DOM node into a string template.

What you should be doing is getting the value of the element `#heading` (since it s a textarea element, it will have the `value` property), not the DOM node itself. This should work:

```
var heading = document.getElementById("heading").value;
```

Comment: Thanks Terry, it's working now. I was wondering if there's any way to programmatically save the new rendered page? It can manually be done with ctrl + S but can be done programatically

Comment: And one more thing, am actually confused when to use .value and when not. If we have to add value into that tag with .innerHTML we don't have to get .value but when we want to do something with the actual input we have to do .value  am I going right?

Comment: The `value` attribute refers to the text the user has entered the textarea. You don't want to inject the entire textarea into the page, do you? You just want to get whatever the user has input into the textarea. Meanwhile you can't really trigger a save function on the page programmatically. The user has to save it him/herself.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you're trying to get the text from the heading element assign it to a new variable and then append it inside the html code.

So what you need to get is the value of the element and not the DOM node:

```
var heading = document.getElementById("heading").value;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ismail, yes value was the problem